# Open graph $_REQUEST and meta tag error

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-opengraph, facebook-canvas

I have been working on a Facebook canvas page app using Codeigniter as a framework and pagoda box as a hosting service. So far I have the app up and running successfully and am now attempting to use open graph to post interactions on peoples timelines. The problem that I am having is that when I plug the URL that I am using into the debugger (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) I get the error:

"You have tags ouside of your . This is either because your was malformed and they fell lower in the parse tree, or you accidentally put your Open Graph tags in the wrong place. Either way you need to fix it before the tags are usable." (verbatim)

I have gone through my code and we haven't found a case where this is true. So I continued debugging and found that the error was centered around a $_REQUEST call to Facebook for the signed_request in the controller. So I surrounded the  $_REQUEST with html  tags which worked as a hack but I'm wondering if there is something better that I could do. Also, it causes the graph api to return:

'"message": "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 2"'

Here's a snippet of my code
Controller:

```
echo '<html>';
echo '<head>';

if(isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {

    $encoded_sig = null;
    $payload = null;
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $_REQUEST['signed_request'], 2);
    $sig = base64_decode(strtr($encoded_sig, '-_', '+/'));
    $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/'), TRUE), TRUE);

} else {
    echo 'error';
}
echo '</head>';
echo '</html>';
```

View:

```
<!doctype html> 

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> 
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# app-name: 
              http://ogp.me/ns/fb/app-name#">

    <title>Facebook Title | Corp Name</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="[Number]" /> 
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="[App-id]" /> 
    <meta property="og:type"   content="app-name:action" /> 
    <meta property="og:url"    content="<?php echo base_url(); ?>" /> 
    <meta property="og:title"  content="The beginning" /> 
    <meta property="og:image"  content="[image-url]" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function postObject()
    {
        FB.api(
            '/me/app-name:object',
            'post',
            { invitation: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>' },
            function(response) {
            if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error occured');
            } else {
                alert('Accept was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
            }
            });
    }
    </script> 

</head>
<body>
....
</body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: There seem to be two questions here: 1) why your document is not validating as an Open Graph object, and 2) how to authenticate a user.

For 1, I'd need to see the page you were debugging. For 2, is there any reason why you don't use the PHP SDK?

Comment: 1. The url for the app directly is http://acceptjesus.pagodabox.com/welcome/authenticate. Unfortunately the app is not yet accessible to the public through Facebook so when it tries to pull up the oauth page it wont work. I'm currently working on making it live. 2. I've got the php sdk included in the project but am not using it in this case because this was my first Facebook app and I foolishly used on of the guides on the Facebook dev page which told me to format the app in this manner.

Comment: Debugging that URL (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Facceptjesus.pagodabox.com%2Fwelcome%2Fauthenticate) shows that there's really only one metadata issue, which is that the og:url field does not match the current URL.

But I see that you are using the JS SDK on the client! So in fact, now I am wondering if you need to do anything on the server side at all. You can use FB.login to do all the authentication in the browser (and then your Open Graph action). Something like https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/ Does that help?

Comment: That does! I'll give it a shot and see what happens. Thank you!